# Difference lubuntu openbox-session: Asked because of aplication error

Tags: ubuntu, desktop-environment, openbox, application

I am trying to run a packaged Electron application at startup to create a "kiosk" system.When i use it in a fresh install of Lubuntu all seems to work fine.

When i install openbox and slim on Ubuntu server with the following packages `mednafen mame git hsetroot python-software-properties software-properties-common xserver-xorg xserver-xorg-core xorg slim libsdl2-dev openbox libgtk2.0-0 libgconf-2-4 libnss3` i get the following error from this application.

```
A JavaScript error occurred in the main process
Uncaught Exception:
Error: Failed to set path
    at Error (native)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/arcadia/arcadia/resources/atom.asar/browser/lib/init.js:115:7)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/arcadia/arcadia/resources/atom.asar/browser/lib/init.js:127:4)
    at Module._compile (module.js:434:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:452:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:475:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:18)
    at node.js:981:3
```

Is there a fundamental difference between these two methods that i don't see? What could be the cause of being unable to run this application in this light environment? Would there be an alternative that i can install and try?

Answer (score 0):

I could not get it to work on Ubuntu so i switched to Debian 8

The following packages have been installed

`d-i pkgsel/include string mednafen mame vim git hsetroot ca-certificates openssl openbox xorg slim libnss3 libgconf-2-4 libatk1.0-0 libatk1.0-data libavahi-client3 libavahi-common-data libavahi-common3 libcups2 libgtk2.0-0 libgtk2.0-common shared-mime-info`